# Trying to read an output from another shell failed

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have this code:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    arr+=("$line")
done < <(isValidParameters < "$1")

printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}"
```

And when I run this, I get no output at all.
What I run is:`./getApartments dos > output.txt`

NOTE: dos is not a real file in my directory, those `isValidParameters` should print: `File is missing`.
Here is `isValidParameters`:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=$PATH:.

if(($# != 1 && $# != 3)); then
    echo "Illegal or missing parameters"
    exit 1
fi

if [[ !(-f $1) ]]; then echo "File is missing";
    exit 1
 fi

#find . $1 \*.flat -print

function search_file() {
    #echo "$1"

    for line in "$1"/*; do 
        if [[ $line == *.flat  && -f "$line" ]]; then
            echo "$line"
         fi

        if [[ $line == *.flat  && -d "$line" ]]; then
            search_file "$line"
        fi
    done
}

while read line; do
    if [[ $line == *.flat  && -f "$line" ]]; then
        echo "$line"
     fi

     if [[ $line == *.flat  && -d "$line" ]]; then
        search_file "$line"
    fi
done < "$1"
```

-------------------------------------------
cleanLines - returns the lines that were sent to it, only changed a bit.
$(cat $path) - will print the content of a specific file consiting of lines.

```
 for path in "${arr[@]}"; do

    while read -r lineOfPath; do
        pathLines+=("$lineOfPath")
    done < <(cleanLines < "$(cat $path)")
done
```

The above example doesn't work. How do I make it work?

Comment: `doc` doesn't match criterion of matching `*.flat` by glob

Comment: @chepner ah i see. crap my eyeballs. then op needs to show `doc` then. that means such pattern doesn't exist in the file.

Comment: When you redirect input from a nonexistent file, the shell reports an error and doesn't run the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isValidParameters` expects to get the filename as argument `$1`, but you're using shell input redirection instead. Since the file doesn't exist, the shell reports the error "dos: No such file or directory" and doesn't run `isvalidParameters` at all.

Change that line to:

```
done < <(isValidParameters "$1")
```

I think you can simplify that loop to:

```
IFS=$'\n' arr=($(isValidParameters "$1"))
```

Comment: Ah-ah! Thank you sir!

Comment: Hi again. What if I wanted to do the very same thing, only that I send a content of a file instead of the file's name? I mean, I wanna add lines to the arr for as much as lines the script I call return.

Comment: `for path in "${arr[@]}"; do
 
 while read -r lineOfPath; do
  pathLines+=("$lineOfPath")
 done < <(cleanLines < "$(cat $path)")
done`

Comment: Something like that. I have also added it to the original post, for your comfort.

Comment: What is in `$path`? I don't understand why you don't just do `<(cleanLines < "$path")`

Comment: I explained it in my original post, see last edit(below everything). Basically, `path` is a path to a file. This file consists of lines. I wanna send that lines to `cleanLines`, and then put all the "cleaned lines" that are returned from `cleanLines` into the array `pathLines`.

Comment: That's what input redirection does. It sends the lines to the standard input of `cleanLines`.

Comment: Or if `cleanLines` expects the filename as `$1`, it should be `<(cleanLines "$path")`.

Comment: `cleanLines` expects a series of lines. As if I printed the file's content into it.